# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing

##Error
I have implemented nested routing in my app. when application loads its shows login screen after login its redirects to admin page where further child routes exist like user, product, api etc. now when I navigate to admin it by default loads user screen but further `<routeLinks>` not working and its shows this error.
`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'product'`

[image]

After Click Product it shows this
[image]

##Code main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '../app/app.routes';
import { AppComponent } from '../app/app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

##app.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  template: `

    <div class="outer-outlet">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

##app.routes

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

import { AboutComponent, AboutHomeComponent, AboutItemComponent } from '../app/about.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../app/home.component';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: HomeComponent
   },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AboutComponent,
    children: [
      { 
        path: '', 
        component: AboutHomeComponent
       },
      { 
        path: '/product', 
        component: AboutItemComponent 
      }
    ]
  }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

##home.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl:'../app/layouts/login.html'
})
export class HomeComponent { }
```

##about.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'about-home',
  template: `<h3>user</h3>`
})
export class AboutHomeComponent { }

@Component({
  selector: 'about-item',
  template: `<h3>product</h3>`
})
export class AboutItemComponent { }

@Component({
    selector: 'app-about',
    templateUrl: '../app/layouts/admin.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AboutComponent { }
```

Comment: Your `app.routes` is identical to `app.component`. Could you please post the proper `app.routes`. I am currently facing the same issue as you.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I think that your mistake is in that your route should be `product` instead of `/product`.

So more something like

```
  children: [
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: AboutHomeComponent
   },
   { 
    path: 'product', 
    component: AboutItemComponent 
   }
 ]
```

Comment: @DylanMeeus i have entred an invalid url in browser then my app redirected to localhost:4200 but its throwing error and not loading home view.

Comment: you could use a wildcard to display a proper 404 page like this: 
`{ path: '**', component: NotFoundCmp }`

Answer (score 15):

I had to use a wildcard route at the end of my routes array.

`{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }`

And the error was resolved.

Answer (score 12):

For me it worked like the code below. I made a difference between `RouterModule.forRoot` and `RouterModule.forChild`. Then in the child define the parent path and in the children array the childs.

**parent-routing.module.ts**

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'parent',  //parent path, define the component that you imported earlier..
    component: ParentComponent,
  }
]),
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: 'parent', //parent path
    children: [
      {
        path: '', 
        redirectTo: '/parent/childs', //full child path
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'childs', 
        component: ParentChildsComponent,
      },
    ]
  }
])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: bad approach i think

Answer (score 12):

I am using angular 4 and faced the same issue apply, all possible solution but finally, this solve my problem

```
export class AppRoutingModule {
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.errorHandler = (error: any) => {
        this.router.navigate(['404']); // or redirect to default route
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this does-nt solve the issue, it just redirect to another page when it happen

Answer (score 8):

I had the issue the imports for the routing module must come after the child module, this might not be directly related to this post but it would have helped me if I read this:

https://angular.io/guide/router#module-import-order-matters

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  ChildModule,
  AppRoutingModule
],
```

Answer (score 3):

If your passing id, then try to follow this method

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  {path:"", redirectTo:"/home", pathMatch:"full"},
  {path:"home", component:HomeComponent},
  {path:"add", component:AddComponent},
  {path:"edit/:id", component:EditComponent},
  {path:"show/:id", component:ShowComponent}
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [

    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same error while I was doing AngularJS application. I did not see any error from my terminal[image: compiled successfully] but when I debug with google developer tool, I have got this error[image: error message].

After having this error, I reviewed my routing module first , since I was not seeing anything while requesting local host /login.

I found out that I misspelled the login as `lgin` and when I correct it works fine. I am just sharing this just to pay attention for any typo error we might encounter with put us in a great time loose!
[image: after correcting the typo error]

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing id through url please use below

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'Employees', component: EmployeesComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'Add', component: EmployeeAddComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      **{ path: 'Edit/:id', component: EmployeeEditComponent },
      { path: 'Edit', component: EmployeeEditComponent },**
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'Employees', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]),
  ],
```

i.e If you are passing any id we need to both url edit with id and edit url alone

Answer (score 1):

As for me `resetConfig` only works

```
this.router.resetConfig(newRoutes);
```

Or concat with previous

```
this.router.resetConfig([...newRoutes, ...this.router.config]);
```

**But keep in mind** that the last must be always route with path `**`

Comment: incomplete answer! it would be better if u elaborate it more. Where did u put the code in first place? module? routing module? inside app component?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. Tried all ways and it didn't work out until I added the following in app.module.ts

```
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';
```

And add the following in your imports in app.module.ts

```
Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot()
```

This case might be rare but I hope this helps someone out there

Answer (score 1):

In my case an `iframe` with a bound `src` was trying to get host/null ( when the value of the bound variable was null ).
Adding an `*ngIf` to it helped.

I changed:

```
<iframe [src]="iframeSource"></iframe>
```

to

```
<iframe [src]="iframeSource" *ngIf="iframeSource"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me adding AppRoutingModule to my imports solved the problem.

```
    imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'new-cmp',
        component: NewCmpComponent
      }
     ])
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**This May be helpful:**

```
//I personally prefer dynamic import (angular 8)
{ path: 'pages', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module').then(mod => mod.PageModule) }
```

In child routing it should look like: `{ path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },`

Note that there is no `pages` in path of child routing and in `routerLink` or `nsRouterLink` it should look like `routerLink="/pages/about"`

I hope thi help someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and later I realised that my app-routing.module.ts was inside a sub folder called app-routing. I moved this file directly under src and now it is working. (Now app-routing file has access to all the components)