# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I am trying to follow this tutorial http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/ but I am getting the error.

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'clients' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'clients'

Here is my `Router module`

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {Routes, RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {ClientComponent} from "./clients/client.component";
import {ClientDetailsComponent} from "./clients/client-details/client-details.component";
import {ClientListComponent} from "./clients/client-list/client-list.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: AppComponent},
    {path: 'clients', component: ClientComponent, children: [
        {path: 'list', component: ClientListComponent, outlet: 'client-list'},
        {path: ':id', component: ClientDetailsComponent, outlet: 'client-details'}
    ]
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})
export class RoutingModule {
}
```

App.component

```
export class AppComponent {
    clientsLoaded = false;

    constructor(private clientService: ClientService,
                private router: Router) {
    }

    loadClientsComponent() {
        this.router.navigate(['/clients', {outlets: {'client-list': ['clients'], 'client-details': ['none'], 'client-accounts-info': ['none']}}]);
        this.clientsLoaded = true;
    }


}
```

Client.component

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ClientService} from "../services/client.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Client} from "./client-details/model/client.model";
@Component({
    selector: 'clients',
    templateUrl: 'app/clients/client.component.html'
})
export class ClientComponent {
    clients: Array<Client> = [];

    constructor(private clientService: ClientService,
                private router: Router) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getClients().subscribe((clients) => {
            this.clients = clients;
        });
    }

    getClients() {
        return this.clientService.getClients();
    }
}
```

What can be wrong ? I would be grateful for any help

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the advice, I have tried something like that

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'clients', component: ClientComponent, children: [
        {path: '', component: ClientComponent},
        {path: 'list', component: ClientListComponent, outlet: 'client-list'},
        {path: ':id', component: ClientDetailsComponent, outlet: 'client-details'}
    ]
    },
];
```

But it still doesn't work.

Maybe I am doing this wrong but I have the following template for my `ClientComponent`

```
<div id="sidebar" class="col-sm-3 client-sidebar">
    <h2 class="sidebar__header">
        Client list
    </h2>
    <div class="sidebar__list">
        <router-outlet name="client-list"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="client-info" class="col-sm-4 client-info">
    <div class="client-info__section client-info__section--general">
        <router-outlet name="client-details"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I want my client component to keep all client related components. And if user clicks for example a button then a client list is loaded.

Comment: Looak at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49962630/5279156

Answer (score 16):

Add `pathMatch: 'full'`

```
{path: '', component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
```

to routes with empty path `''` and no child routes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this doesn't work either. What else can cause the problem ?

Comment: `/clients` is not a valid route. You need `/clients/list` or `/clients/someid` or add a default route `path: ''` to children of `/clients` with a redirect to `list`

Comment: Thank you so much, but this still doesn't work, I have just update my question, please have a look.

Comment: I'm not fluent with named outlets. AFAIK you still need one unnamed outlet (named outlets can only be used in addition to unnamed - I remember some discussion that this restriction might be removed but I don't remember seeing anything that this actually happende. I'd suggest you try first without named outlets at all, and when this works add named outlets as a next step.

Comment: Thanks I will try, please add your comments to the answer, I think they might be helpful for others

Comment: Comments can be read as well ;-). Let's see what your experiments reveal and then maybe I'll do some final updates.

Answer (score 2):

I am integrating Angular 2/4 into an existing MVC application, and I had this problem too.

Using your example, if I had `path: 'Clients'` in the routing config instead of `path: 'clients'` and tried to go to the URL such as `http://localhost/clients`, I would get this error.

The route path names are case sensitive (as of right now anyway). They won't match what's in your URL otherwise, and with typical MVC controller/action naming, they are "InitialCaps-style."

Answer (score 1):

Check the imports session at the **app.module.ts** and look you did't miss the routing:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    APP_ROUTES,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my path was correct.
At my end cleaning ClientApp\dist folder solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, make sure that the module **`RouterTestingModule`** is not imported in corresponding `module.ts` file by mistake.